# Where is my mistake in this matrix representation problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

$\text{Let: } \alpha = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\0&0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\1&0 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\0&1 \end{bmatrix} \right\} \quad \beta = \{1,x,x^2\} \\
T:P_2(\mathbb{R}) \mapsto M_{2\times2} := T(f(x))=\begin{bmatrix} f'(0) & 2f(1) \\ 0 & f''(3) \end{bmatrix} \\
\text{Compute: } [T]_{\beta}^{\alpha} \\
T[1] = \begin{bmatrix} 0&2\\0&0 \end{bmatrix} \implies [T(1)]_\alpha= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\\
T[x] = \begin{bmatrix} 1&2\\0&0 \end{bmatrix} \implies [T(x)]_\alpha = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\\\\
T[x^2] = \begin{bmatrix} 1&2\\0&2 \end{bmatrix} \implies [T(x^2)]_\alpha = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}\\\\
\text{So, by the definition of matrix representations:}\\
A=[T]_{\alpha}^{\beta} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}
$

Comment: I see my mistake. I evaluated $f'(0) = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $T[x^2]$ is wrong because $(x^2)'=2x$ so $f'(0)=0$

Comment: Sure. When evaluating matrix representations of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n$, do we just evaluate the transformation for each element in the basis? I suppose so. If the basis $\beta = \{ 1,x,x^2+1} \} $ then the evaluation would necessarily make the entry $a_{13} = 1$ but the rest of the elements in that column would be different.